# Covering Variation of Longest Common Substring

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, combinatorics

> Given three binary strings, find the maximum possible length of a contiguous block of 1's formed by shifting and overlapping the strings.

This may be interpreted as finding the maximum window size $k$ such that for each column $(a, b, c)$ across the three strings, it holds that $a \lor b \lor c$ is true. If we instead require $a = b = c$, then we recover the original [longest common substring (LCS) problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), for which there is a [linear time algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/105969/longest-common-substring-in-linear-time) using suffix arrays. Can a similar linear time result be achieved here?

[image: example problem instance]

Comment: I don’t see how to get linear time even for 2 strings. The only efficient thing I can think of is FFT, since it allows one to “find X for all possible shifts of two arrays”.